# Gitlab Option to create branch/merge request for issue automatically

Tags: gitlab, issue-tracking, feature-branch, merge-request

Is there an option in GitLab which enables feature branch/merge request creation by default whenever an issue is created?

I know it is possible to create them manually by clicking that fancy button on the issue page, but let's face it, we're lazy...

Comment: As @olearycrew suggested: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/219476

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that option already exists - as you mentioned there *is* the fancy button but I don't think there is a way to click it automatically if you will.

One drawback of this would be that every issue, even those you may not end up implementing, would get a branch.

Could you [open an issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues) to discuss this possibility?